# Where do you ask questions about finding names of ethnic groups?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I read an article about 20 years ago in a periodical about a tribe of people that could walk straight up to a deer without the deer knowing they were there. They were required to pluck a hair from a live deer's tail as a type of initiation or as a show of skill. I'm trying to rediscover this tribe again but I'm having no luck. Is there a site where I can ask if anyone knows who these people were?

Comment: Maybe Genealogy or History or no where.

Comment: The tribe can't be rediscovered because the big cats had an initiation ritual of sneaking up on hunters who were sneaking up on deer....

Comment: If you wrap it up properly, it can be on-topic on Travel, I guess – but do not let them find this comment.

Comment: I asked [the question on History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/21431/who-were-the-deer-touchers), and it has so far been well received there.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Anything is on topic on  [travel.se] if you disguise it :P http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46345/where-is-the-quietest-place-on-earth